# Only autocomplete on an exact match in Sublime Text 2

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

I'm making a custom `.tmLanguage` file to highlight the syntax I'm using correctly and generally make coding with it easier. I'm almost done, and I got the autocompletion working using a `.sublime-completions` file.

There's just one minor flaw I'd like to change. I have a pretty long list of functions, and almost all of them contain an abbreviation of the word 'parameter', `PAR`. When I start typing that word, the following are all in the list of completions:

- PAR command
- DEFPAR command
- JDATA command (because the description contains PAR)
- SPAA command (because there's a P in the command and an A and an R in the description)

What I want is only for the commands that begin with `PAR` to show up, so from the list above, only the first item.

So, like this:

[image: Example completions list with faulty items]

In other words, I want the completions to show up based on the literal string I'm typing, and only from the `trigger` part of my completions file, before the `\t` only.

That completions file looks like this:

[image: Example .sublime-completions file]

Highlighted in orange is what I want my completions list to be based on.

I hope this is understandable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. By design Sublime's autocomplete feature uses fuzzy matching, so if there are a number of options that all contain the same pattern, but you don't quite remember which one you want, you can type the pattern and have all of the options available. The more you type, the smaller the list of possible options becomes. This is a good thing®, otherwise you'd have to remember the exact command you're looking for, which kind of defeats the purpose of autocomplete and code hinting.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to have quote from some documentation for future reference?